# Convert HTML2HAML - jQuery Tabs

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, tabs, haml

So I used the html2haml converter to convert the following:

https://gist.github.com/1379702

from

http://css-tricks.com/2361-jquery-ui-tabs-with-nextprevious/

to haml, however I can't get it to work on my site, so I was wondering if the haml was still messed up since I am just using a converting script.

I put the javscript files in the correct locations in the assest/javascript folder, and the css in stylesheets.

Thanks,

> **UPDATE**: I am using the following code on my rails project https://gist.github.com/1379734

Comment: some errors would be real useful. You've tagged this question as rails. What's up with `<?php set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); ?>`?

Comment: There isn't an error per se - but rather it results in this http://ScrnSht.com/vxusvv the code I am using on rails actually looks like this https://gist.github.com/1379734 it should look like this http://ScrnSht.com/nidtte in terms of how the tabs and next/previous button is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the ordering of the .js files - [jquery ui not working completely (stable "jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690987/jquery-ui-not-working-completely-stable-jquery-ui-1-8-16-custom-min-js) though that doesn't solve the issue of the next button working, but that's a different stackoverflow question.