# Debug strategy for Javascript "TypeError: elem.dispatchEvent is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I'm getting this error in Firebug when using jQuery 2.0.3 and the [filedrop](https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop) HTML5 uploader script on Firefox 24 on Mac OSX.

The problem is that Firebug reports a seemingly incorrect line number for the error - it always reports line 54 of my HTML markup, regardless of what is on that line - I've tried changing it. It never reports a line number that is actually javascript.

When Firebug is disabled, the script appears to work without issue.

So given that this line number is of no help, what strategy can I use to find the source of this error?
The only thing I can think of is to add `console.log()` lines before and after evey statement in my code. Is there a better way, or is there a way to find out if this is some sort of observer effect?

**What I've tried:**

- Searched for the error, results mostly suggest that it's a jQuery
  conflict with another library, but I only use jQuery and have tried
  the fix regardless.
- Tried adding log lines to statements in the code, nothing useful yet 
  but adding more.
- Related: ["element.dispatchEvent is not a function" js error caught in firebug of FF3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980697/element-dispatchevent-is-not-a-function-js-error-caught-in-firebug-of-ff3-0)

Comment: Did you set your debugger to [break on errors](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Break_On_...)?

Comment: @epascarello Yes, I've just tried disabling break on error and tried again - the error crops up dozens of times, it appears to be something to do with the progress callback... beats me why I get an odd line number though.

Comment: Are you using a minimized version of the code? Use the full version.

Comment: only jQuery is minimised, i'll try with unminimised though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Firebug up to version 1.12.8, which was reported as [issue 5939](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5939).

The problem can be solved in two ways:

1. **Install the latest version of Firebug**
   Firebug 2.0 [switched to new Firefox debugger APIs](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5421), which fix a lot of bugs the old APIs had.
2. **Disable the *Script* panel**
   If you can't or don't want to install newer versions of Firebug for whatever reason, you can disable the *Script* panel temporarily and then reproduce your error. Then the correct line number should be reported.

Comment: disabling the script panel had no effect, the console still showed the incorrect line number. I'm using FB version 1.12.4 - thanks for trying but no dice :(

Comment: Hmm, there are [some other issues](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list?can=2&q=wrong+line+label%3Aconsole) talking about similar problems. It would be great if you could come up with a reproducible test case and post it to the [Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/firebug), so the bug can be investigated.

Comment: I took out fireQuery and that resolved my problem, I'm blaming that extension.

Comment: That works for me too. After disabled FireQuery and stop getting the dispatchEvent is not a function error