# New firefox + firebug breaks select2 in wrapbootstrap pixel-admin theme

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, firebug, jquery-select2

I'm getting a **TypeError: elem.dispatchEvent is not a function** using  select2 in jquery using the wrapbootsrap pixel-admin theme.

It can be reproduced in firebug on the demo site via http://radiant-ocean-4606.herokuapp.com/forms-advanced.html

*Firefox Version: 29.0.1*
 *Firebug Version: 1.12.8*

It's a similar error message to this question:

["element.dispatchEvent is not a function" js error caught in firebug of FF3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980697/element-dispatchevent-is-not-a-function-js-error-caught-in-firebug-of-ff3-0)

But the answer there doesn't help me as my site is all jquery (well as far as I know - I did somewhat accept the theme bundle as it came for the time being until I have time to really rip it apart and modify it in detail).

Comment: and the page works fine when bugs of fire is closed

Comment: What means "new Firefox + Firebug"? Which versions?

Comment: Firefox Version: 29.0.1 Firebug Version: 1.12.8 - added to question, thanks - valid point.  Seems like these are the latest stable releases - they updated themselves.

Comment: I'm seeing all kinds of "firebug script stopped working" errors as well.  I've just disabled all my addons to see if I can track down the real source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by changes to the browser, the solution was to stop using firebug. The features firebug offered are ubiquitous now!