# How to fix “element.dispatchEvent is not a function” without breaking something else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dispatchevent

I have same problem as ["element.dispatchEvent is not a function" js error caught in firebug of FF3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980697/element-dispatchevent-is-not-a-function-js-error-caught-in-firebug-of-ff3-0) but in google chrome.

I have wrote `<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>`
after all scripts. But now I have another problem:

```
  ...
  $("a.try").click(function () {
  ...
```

undefined is not a function

and

```
 ...
 var blockHeight = $(window).height();
 ...
```

undefined is not a function

Thus first fix is not valid.

P.S.

html part where I include scripts:

```
....
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<c:url value='/resources/js/underscore.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'/>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery.mousewheel.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<c:url value='/resources/js/popup.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js'/>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<c:url value='/resources/js/scroll-startstop.events.jquery.js'/>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js'/>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<c:url value='/resources/js/script-ini.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<c:url value='/resources/js/map/map.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>

<script type="text/template" id="terminal-template">
    ...
</script>
<style>
    .grey-terminal {
        background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<c:url value='/resources/js/addTerminal.js'/>"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
...
```

Can you advise another way?

Comment: jQuery is not loaded.... and noConflict should be at before of using the script not after the script...

Comment: @Bhojendra - C-Link Nepal please read my update. Can you advice how to rewrite this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `jQuery.noConflict();` you no longer associate `jQuery` with the `$` variable.

So things like `$().click` or `$(selector)` will throw errors. Instead, you can do something like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery('a.try').click(handler);
jQuery(window).height();
```

Or, you can also assign jQuery to a new variable, like this:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$('a.try').click(handler);
j$(window).height();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wL4mc03a/

**Edit**

As for dispatching events, one way you can do this (using jQuery) is to `trigger` the event. Say you have some code that looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.which === 42) {
        alert('That is the key to life!');
    }
});
```

Later, you can trigger this event. Instead of triggering the event using a string ('keydown'), we'll create an jQuery event and pass that.

```
var evt = jQuery.Event('keydown');
evt.which = 42;

jQuery(document).trigger(evt);
```

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite var 'event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown');
$("#pac-input").dispatchEvent(event);' without jquery?

Comment: Yes, you can. However, you'll need to call it like `$('#pac-input').get(0).dispatchEvent(event)`. `get` will return the DOM node (rather than the jQuery-wrapped object). However, if you want to do it the jQuery way (which I recommend), you could just `trigger` the event like `$('#pac-input').trigger('keydown')` (if you need to specify the key, you can pass a second argument as an object like `$('#input').trigger('keydown', {which:42})` - the second object simulates the event object.

Comment: **var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{which:42});
$("#pac-input").get(0).dispatchEvent(event);**  When I invoke this I see that executes event which invoke when I type text. i need invoke enter event

Comment: **($('#pac-input').trigger('keydown', {which:42})**  doesn't work

Comment: Oh, for enter, you'll need to pass the correct `keycode` (which isn't 42, I believe). How does your code check to see if it's an enter key? Are you using `e.which`? I'll throw together a fiddle for you really quickly...

Comment: Ok, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/46e7tksr/ - I apologize as I gave incorrect info earlier. The additional arguments from trigger are not passed in the event object, but rather, as an additional argument (to the event) - so you would need to check for (e.which || data.which) - if you use trigger.

Comment: Here's using jQuery's version of dispatchEvent (and creating a new event) - http://jsfiddle.net/46e7tksr/1/ Which removes the need to check a second argument (since you're creating an event) - This, for me, is cleaner

Answer (score 1):

This helped me!
Adding jQuery.noConflict(); just before starting the jquery code and then replacing all '$' with 'jQuery'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        ....
        ....
    });
</script>
```

Same as mentioned in the above solution @Jack