# Uncaught TypeError: child.dispatchEvent is not a function EaselJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, createjs, easeljs

I'm trying to create a card game using [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/easeljs). I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: child.dispatchEvent is not a function EaselJS` error when trying to add an object class to the stage it seems. I am using `jQuery`, but I've followed [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980697/element-dispatchevent-is-not-a-function-js-error-caught-in-firebug-of-ff3-0) to remove the jQuery conflict:

```
    <script src="lib/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

I'm also using RaphaelJS, but am phasing it out. I thought this library may also be a conflict, so I simply completely removed the `jQuery` and `raphaelJS` inclusions and still had the same error.

**Code snippets:**

```
this.tableCanvas = new createjs.Stage('Table');

function createDeck () {

        for (var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
                    var card_data = { ... };
                    var card = new Card(this.tableCanvas, card_data);
                    ...
                }
         }
         this.tableCanvas.update();
```

**Card class:** I'm console logging the `canvas` to ensure I am not losing context and it is in fact logging the correct Stage object.

```
var Card = function(canvas, args) {

    var graphics = new createjs.Graphics();
    graphics.beginStroke("red").beginFill("blue").drawRect(20, 20, 100, 50);
    this.shape = new createjs.Shape(graphics);
    this.set = new createjs.Container();
    this.set.addChild(this.shape);
    this.set.x = this.x;
    this.set.y = this.y;
    console.log('canvas', canvas);  //outputs createJS Stage object
    canvas.addChild(this); //Error seems to be because of this
```

I've also tried adding the card inside the creation loop:

```
for ...
     for ...
         var card = new Card(this.tableCanvas, card_data);
         this.tableCanvas.addChild(card); 
     }
}
```

Same error.

**HTML snippet:**

```
<body>
    <div id="GameBoard">
        <canvas id="Table" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

Error: createjs-2015.11.26.combined.js:7322

```
p.addChild = function(child) {
    if (child == null) { return child; }
    var l = arguments.length;
    if (l > 1) {
        for (var i=0; i<l; i++) { this.addChild(arguments[i]); }
        return arguments[l-1];
    }
    if (child.parent) { child.parent.removeChild(child); }
    child.parent = this;
    this.children.push(child);
    child.dispatchEvent("added"); //ERROR HERE
    return child;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you are adding Card instances to the stage. Stage children need to be DisplayObjects. You should be adding `this.set` to the `canvas` instead.

I would also recommend your second approach.

```
this.tableCanvas.addChild(card.set);
```